# OWL Carousel 2 - slide more than 1 item with dots

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, owl-carousel

I use OWL Carousel 2, I disable navigation and I want to use the Dots for navigation.

Right now I have 15 items and I have 15 dots too, is there any way to have for example 3 Dots and to slide 5 items when I press on first Dot? Like in this image:

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>13</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>14</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>15</h4></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- latest jquery file -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  (function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        nav:false,
        dots:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            600:{
                items:3
            },
            1000:{
                items:5
            }
        }
    })

  })(jQuery); 
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.item{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much is work like a charm, I really appreciate your help.